# How can I isolate the tooltip effect to span just one word?

Tags: html, tooltip

```
`<h6><u>TIP</u>: Hover over underlined words for more info</h6>`

`<p title="A delicious bread based food with tomato sauce, served open with melted cheese and other toppings optional"><u>Pizza</u> was used to ensure that the everyone was satisfied during Sprint planning, even if they weren't satisfied with the plan itself :-)</p>`
```

---

In the above HTML code, the title tag is giving a tooltip effect on the paragraph. How can this be isolated to span only one word, for this example, the word "Pizza" at the beginning of the sentence, which is also underlined?

Things tried:

1. Putting the span tags before the title tag and after the word pizza (including the underline tag).
2. Alternatively trying the tooltip as a link with tooltip in the span like this (got this from a post in Stackoverflow):

   `<a href="#">Text <span>Tooltip</span></a>t`
3. Using a reverse editor (html-online.com) to play around with it.
4. introducing CSS, code example (also gotten from stackoverflow):

   `.tooltip { position: relative; display: inline-block; border-bottom: 1px dotted black;   }`
5. Lastly I tried looking around google and stackoverflow using tags "html" and "tooltip" for the same question answered already, no results. Maybe it's such a basic question that nobody would ask it here, but I am just learning from youtube videos from scratch, any tips appreciated, thank you for your time :-)

Comment: @iPoetDev have any idea about this one?

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods, however you need to think about screen readers and the non-sighted/low vision users, so think semantic html. It all depends on your use case.

Head on over to MDN for a great resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Reference

Option 1:
You may look at the semantic use of the  tag for a definition of a word. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dfn

Option 2:
You may look at the semantic use of  for an abbreviation. This can be used with the dfn tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/abbr

Option 3:
You can use span with aria labels to make it relevant to screen readers, however, spans and divs are not semantic by default. Try to avoid using spans if the meaning is semantically relevant. Spans are good for UI and interactive functionality as my preference. Do not forget tags that have a closer coupling and purpose to your use case.

Option 4:
You could use CSS :hover, :target on a span: dfn, abbr elememts to add a visual, not semantic, purely presentational only and non a11y styling to the title.

Additionally
And you can CSS selector element[title] and style those elements that have a title.

Note that the title attribute is the one providing the tooltip hover as a global attribute, and it is available on all tags. Use wisely and sparingly.

And finally, look beyond stack overflow and at web.dev, css tricks and other html/css/browser/front end specialist places.

Here is an advanced one
https://stackdiary.com/useful-css-tricks/#simple-tooltip-using-attr

And please avoid using `<u>`, `<i>` etc tags ... these are no longer kosher in use and are only kept in the HTML spec for backwards compatibility.

Comment: that all gave me stuff to research and learn, I hadn't come across aria labels or the dfn tag yet, both were good to look at but neither achieved the effect I was wondering about.

In essence, I'm not really thinking of users here, I'm just trying to learn the limitations of the bits I learn, so I learned the attribute title, but wanted to figure out if it could be isolated to one word like tags could, just to know what possibilities vs limitations are of the language as I go.

Comment: Got it! I tried your Option 3 but without the aria label and it worked. Also found this page useful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

The code looked like this:

    `<p><span title="A delicious bread based food with tomato sauce, served open with melted cheese and other toppings optional" ><u>Pizza</u></span> was used to ensure that the everyone was satisfied during Sprint planning, even if they weren't satisfied with the plan itself. </p>`